# Angular FormGroup get array of selected checkboxes

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

How can I receive a array of selected checkboxes? All I get returned is true. This is my code:

```
  <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="postData()">
    <div *ngFor="let customers of customerslist$">
      <div *ngFor="let item of customers.data">
        {{ item.id }} <input type="checkbox" formControlName="company" value="{{ item.company }}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> send</button>
  </form>
```

Component:

```
 form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private customerdataService: CustomerDataService,private router: Router,private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { 
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      company: []
    });
  }
```

How to select selected items in postData()

```
  postData() {
    const selectedCustomer = this.form.value.company
      
    console.log(selectedCustomer);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only have 1 formControlName="company". Even though you created multiple input checkboxes they all have the same name which is "company". I believe that is the reason why you only get one value instead of an array. I think you can try using item.company inside your "formControlName" to have different names. Like this one.

```
{{ item.id }} <input type="checkbox" formControlName="item.company" value="{{ item.company }}">
```

Comment: Yes this is needed. they are used as array